# PHP - Linebreaks are missing after posting

Tags: php, curl, line-breaks

I'm posting a message like the one below to Facebook via PHP cURL:

```
Hello world

This is a test

#hash
```

The entry on the Facebook wall is missing the linebreaks - the text looks like this:

```
Hello world This is a test #hash
```

This is my code:

```
$attachment =  array(
'access_token' => $token,
'message' => $postMessage
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$profileID.'/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

How to make the linebreaks are send to?

P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: Try to use \n in your $postMessage, maybe it works

Comment: Or if what @Rsauxil says doesn't work, try <br> tags?

Comment: Run your content the nl2br function or style the containing element with white-space:pre-wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [**nl2br**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function

```
$attachment =  array(
'access_token' => $token,
'message' => nl2br($postMessage)
);
```

Comment: OK, this "workaround" is working: `$postMessage = nl2br($_POST["message"]); 
$postMessage = str_replace("<br />", "\n", $postMessage);` Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this old, but in case it helps someone else, I have better luck with `json_encode` / `json_decode`